# What is an accordion called that can expand more than one panel at a time?

Tags: jquery, accordion

Can someone please tell me what is the name of a widget that works like an accordion but where you can expand more than one containter/panel at a time. I am very new to all this programming lingo?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a series of collapsible panel or div:

http://www.darreningram.net/pages/examples/jQuery/CollapsiblePanelPlugin.aspx

An accordion is just a set of collapsible divs that keep one open at a time.